# How many games should one play online per day or week?

Tags: online-chess, websites, online

I participated in a tournament on `chess.com` and I have to play like 12 games, 3 days per move, although it's plenty of time, I can't concentrate, I noticed that when I play many games, I lose because I make mistakes.

The thing is when you have 12 games to be played, you often find yourself, not playing at all or playing all the games simultaneously, to just get over with it, and do something else other than playing chess.

So in an ideal situation, what is the best number of games to be played per day or week for average users?

A side question, is it good to play such tournaments? I mean when you have many games to be played, you'll lose concentration (at least I do) so isn't it better to play live tournaments (15 or 30 min for each player) isn't that a better way to concentrate on the moves?

Comment: Interesting question Fischer I am also a regular chess.com player for 2yrs now.

Comment: How much time do you have to waste?  No you should not play so many postal games at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since playing chess is not a job for most of us, it may not make much sense to ask how many games **should** you play. Some people relish the adrenaline rush of 1 minute chess, some can play for hours, some like to play three games at once... and then some others like to play once a week. The answer depends on who you are, but since it seems that online tourneys stress you out, it may be better for you to attend live ones.

I know this is not much of an answer, but I think it is closest to the truth.

Comment: lets say one plays 6 games a day, will he be able to have the same winning average like another player who plays 2 games per week?

Comment: @Fischer If he wins the same percentage of games, yes.

Answer (score 4):

This is like asking "what is the ideal number of hours to read each week".

The answer is: it depends on the person.

The only solution is to experiment with different numbers and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get so many games that you lose concentration. Play a few games, but keep it enjoyable. I find I do well with 18 or 20 games, but 40 or more makes me a little crazy. Just do what you are comfortable with. It is different for every person, so we need to find our own level. And, of coarse, how much time you have to play is a big factor.

Answer (score 1):

As a regular chess.com player I stick with 10 to 15 daily games of 3days per move. I do not play greater than 15 games as I cannot concentrate on it.

I suggest stick only with games that you can accommodate, games which you can ANALYZE better without a rush.

I you got bored with your opponents in "Daily move chess" try to log and play in blitz or 15mins per move games until you get satisfied.